# Does global function for loop run parallel or not?

Tags: c++, cuda

This code block is properly running.But I wonder inside the for loop is running as parallel(in cuda) or is it running serial ?

```
const int xIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
const int yIndex = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int tid = yIndex * blockDim.x + xIndex;
float resultOneDimensional = 0;

if((xIndex < width) && (yIndex < height)){
    const int input_tid = yIndex * inputWidthStep + xIndex;
    const int buffer_tid = yIndex * bufferWidthStep + (xIndex * CHANNEL);
    const float readFrame = input[input_tid];
    output[buffer_tid + bufferSize] = readFrame;

    for (tid = 0; tid < CHANNEL; tid++){
         resultOneDimensional += (output[buffer_tid + bufferSize + tid] / (CHANNEL));
    }
    outputOneDimensional[input_tid] = static_cast<unsigned char>(resultOneDimensional);
}
```

Comment: Please, you either program in C or in C++, but very seldom both. The code you show isn't valid C so please [edit] your question to remove the C language tag.

Answer (score 3):

Each thread of your kernel will run that for-loop.

The for-loop itself runs serially, in the context of a single thread.

That means thread 0 will execute a copy of the for-loop, and thread 0 will start the loop at its `tid` value (probably 0), and thread 0 will execute the body of the for-loop `CHANNEL-tid` times.

Likewise, thread 1 will execute a copy of the for-loop, and thread 1 will start the loop at its `tid` value (probably 1), and thread 1 will execute the body of the for-loop `CHANNEL-tid` times.

And so on, for other threads in your kernel (grid).

Comment: This code lines are inside of __global__ Cuda function , so is that for loop still serially?Thank you!

Comment: So how to design these codes to run it parallel?

Comment: Yes, its evident from your code (e.g. the usage of `blockIdx.x` that this is kernel code running in a kernel (a `__global__`  CUDA function is called a kernel).  Your for-loops appear to be doing a reduction.  To run a single one of those "in parallel" I would use a [parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) method.